# Setting background image to compose Column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I want to set background of a column as image instead of color.
We set the background color as this
`Column(modifier = Modifier.background(Colors.Blue) )`

so instead of this, I want to use an image to set as background.

I tried setting it using painter of the modifier.

`val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter( "imageUrl",contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight)`

`Column(modifier = Modifier.paint(painter) )`
But this is not setting the image to the complete column height and width.

Is there any way I can set the image directly to the column composable instead of using Box and other composables?
I am using **coil** to download the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `paint` modifier applying the `contentScale`.

Something like:

```
val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data(url)
        .size(ORIGINAL)
        .build(),
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
)

Column(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .paint(
            painter,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
        )
) {
   //content....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gabriele,  adding ` contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds`  solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this for fill height and width, as you use coil `(io.coil-kt:coil-compose)`.

```kotlin
WrapperBoxImage(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                    imgUrl = "your image url.....",
                    placeholder = R.drawable.ic_default_class_image,
                    scale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    contentDescription = "course_card_image"
                )
```

if you need rounded corners just add this `.clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))` to modifier of WrapperBoxImage.

Our `WrapperBoxImage` Implementation will look like,

```kotlin
const val contentDescription_default = "WrapperBox_Image"

@Composable
fun WrapperBoxImage(
    mod: Modifier = Modifier,
    imgUrl: String,
    placeholder: Int = R.drawable.image_video_placeholder,
    scale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    contentDescription: String,
    onClick: () -> Unit = {}
) {
    Box(
        modifier = mod.clickable { onClick() }
    ) {
        ImageSpec(imgUrl, placeholder, scale = scale, contentDescription = contentDescription)
    }
}

@Composable
private
fun ImageSpec(
    imgUrl: String,
    placeholder: Int = R.drawable.image_video_placeholder,
    mod: Modifier = Modifier,
    scale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    contentDescription: String = contentDescription_default
) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
            ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current).data(data = imgUrl)
                .apply(block = fun ImageRequest.Builder.() {
                    placeholder(placeholder)
                    scale(Scale.FILL)
                }).build()
        )
        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = contentDescription,
            mod.fillMaxSize(),
            contentScale = scale
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer J.K but I have to add a background image to the column only. I can not use other composable. Anyway, @2016562 has given a solution and it works.